# Pandas vs Dask sort columns and index of string and number

Tags: python, pandas, dask

**Given**:

Small sample pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({"usr": ["ip1", "ip7", "ip12", "ip4"], "colB": [1, 2, 3, 0], "ColA": [3, np.nan, 7, 1]}, dtype="float32").set_index("usr")
    
        colB    ColA
usr         
ip1     1.0     3.0
ip7     2.0     NaN
ip12    3.0     7.0
ip4     0.0     1.0
```

I can sort this dataframe for both index and columns using `sort_index` and `reindex` as follows:

```
df_s = df.sort_index(key=lambda x: ( x.to_series().str[2:].astype(int) )) # sort index
df_s = df_s.reindex(columns=sorted(df_s.columns)) # sort columns

        ColA    colB
usr         
ip1     3.0     1.0
ip4     1.0     0.0
ip7     NaN     2.0
ip12    7.0     3.0
```

**Problem**:

My real dataset is a large dataframe and I use Dask to benefit from parallel computing. Since `sort_index` does not exist in Dask, I try to use `sort_values` as follows:

```
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
ddf_s = ddf.map_partitions(lambda inp_ddf: inp_ddf.sort_values( ["usr"], ascending=True) ).compute()
```

But I get completely different results compared to my `df_s`. Neither index nor columns got sorted properly.

```
        ColA    colB
usr         
ip1     3.0     1.0
ip4     1.0     0.0
ip7     NaN     2.0
ip12    7.0     3.0
```

How do I have to sort index and columns in Dask?

Cheers,

Comment: Could you replace your images with formatted text? See also [Why should I not upload images code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to sort each partiotion like this:

```py
ddf.map_partitions(
    lambda inp_ddf: inp_ddf.sort_values( ....
```

It will result in dataset that contains sorted partitions but not sorted result.

I ended with this version.

```py
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df.reset_index(), npartitions=2) # to make ip normal column
ddf_s = ddf.assign(
    n=ddf['usr'].str[2:].astype(int) # create the new column to able to sort (1, 7, 12, 4)
).set_index(
    'usr' # restore index back
).sort_values(
    ['n'] # sort by values
).drop(
    columns=['n'] # cleanup the created column
)
```

Finally to sort columns I recomend to just manipulate with output data and order of columns

```py
ddf_s[sorted(ddf_s.columns)].compute()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the columns in your answer is not sorted properly. I want to get both index and columns sorted

Comment: Actually it will not sort index propertly as well. Due to npartitions=2 will split orig df to ip1, ip12 and ip4, ip7. In result it will sort them separatly.

Comment: Rework whole answer. Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks a a lot for your answer! It completely fixes my problem now! I just added `.compute()` right after `ddf_s[sorted(ddf_s.columns)]`

Comment: @FaridAlijani Thank you for this addition. I update my answer to have final solution.